# SML map function

Tags: sml, smlnj, currying, partial-application, map-function

I have the function:

```
map(map(fn x =>[x])) [[],[1],[2,3,4]];
```

Which produces:

```
val it = [[],[[1]],[[2],[3],[4]]]
```

I don't understand how this function works. Doesn't each map function need both a function and a list? It seems that there isn't enough arguments for this to actually execute.

If I run:

```
map(fn x =>[x]) [[],[1],[2,3,4]];
```

I get:

```
val it = [[[]], [[1]], [[2,3,4]]];
```

Which makes more sense to me, as it takes each element in the list, and wraps it in another list. But when I put another map on it, it changes the output. Can anyone explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You said:

> I don't understand how this function works. Doesn't each map function need both a function and a list?

Well, keep in mind than, in Standard ML (and, in general, all applicative languages), there is no such thing as a "function of n parameters", for "n" other than 1. However, functions of more than one parameter can be *simulated* in two ways:

1. As functions of a single parameter that is a tuple or record. The original intended parameters can be recovered in the function's body by means of projection from the tuple or record.
2. As functions of the first parameter that return a function of the remaining parameters.

With this in mind, we check `map`'s type in the REPL:

```
> map;
val it = fn: ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

(I use Poly/ML, not SML/NJ, but formatting issues aside, the output should be the same.)

No tuples, no records. `map` clearly takes the second approach to simulating a function of two parameters: it takes a function of type `'a -> 'b` and returns *another* function of type `'a list -> 'b list`.

Now, here is the catch: For any function `foo`, `map foo` is a function as well! Since `map` can take *any* function as argument, `map foo` is itself a perfectly legitimate argument for `map`. Which means that `map (map foo)` typechecks for any function `foo`. In particular, this is true if `val foo = fn x => [x]`.

---

You said:

> It seems that there isn't enough arguments for this to actually execute.

If it typechecks, it runs.

---

You said:

> If I run
>
> ```
> map (fn x => [x]) [[], [1], [2,3,4]]
> ```
>
> I get
>
> ```
> val it = [[[]], [[1]], [[2,3,4]]];
> ```
>
> Which makes more sense to me, as it takes each element in the list, and wraps it in another list. But when I put another map on it, it changes the output.

Let's refactor your code a little bit, without changing its meaning:

```
let
  val foo = fn x => [x]
  val bar = map foo
  val baz = map bar
in
  baz [[], [1], [2,3,4]]
end
```

Now we can analyze what every function (`foo`, `bar`, `baz`) does to its parameter:

1. `foo` takes a single element `x` and wraps it in a list data constructor.
2. `bar` takes a list of elements, wraps each element in a list data constructor, and returns a list with the resulting wrapped elements (a list of lists).
3. `baz` takes a (super)list of (sub)lists of elements, applies `bar` to every sublist, and returns a list with the results.

Perform all of this manually to convince yourself that the result, `[[], [[1]], [[2], [3], [4]]]`, is indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
 map ;
 val it = fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list
```

so map takes a function which again takes a list and gives a list  .

So define map with function

```
-fun f x = x+1 ;
val f = fn : int -> int
-map f ;
val it = fn : int list -> int list
```

now `it` is that type of function which takes list and return a list

```
- it [1,2] ;
val it = [2,3] : int list
```

I think the map function is clear